# Can't insert 9k words to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data txt files to my MySQL DB. And files which have 100-400 words are inserting great. No problem with them. But today I got a file with 9k words, and my script stopped working. It inserts or Updates nothing. Have I problems with my script or should I make parts of this file? What is the better solution?

Here is my code:

```
//$arr - array from file; 

foreach ($arr as $temp)
{
    $w_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $temp[0]); 
    $w_minprice = $temp[2];
    $w_js_id = $temp[1];
    $w_s = $temp[3];

    $sql ="SELECT `js_id` FROM `mytable` WHERE `js_id` = '$w_js_id' LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    list($temp2) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    if ($temp2 == '')
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`, `minprice`, `s`, `js_id`, `pl`) VALUES ('$w_name', '$w_minprice', '$w_s',  '$w_js_id', '$pl')";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($result) {$added++;}
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE `mytable` SET `minprice` = '$w_minprice', `s` = '$g_s' WHERE `js_id` = '$w_js_id' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($result) {$updated++;}
    }
}
```

Perhaps should I do multiple queries? Or divide my queries to 10? But how? I am not strong in MySQL queries.
My goal is to insert an array with 9 000 values to my db.

UPDATE: I added this lines:
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
added in my mysql:
max_allowed_packet = 32M;

And it solved my problem with the script!

Comment: What is the column Data type?

Comment: I suspect you are exceeding the length allowed by the data type of the column.

Comment: If its `TEXT` then use `LONGTEXT`

Comment: Does $added and $updated increase. You could be hitting the PHP memory limit putting the file into an array and not doing any queries. Check your error log.

Comment: I assume you are getting no error message(s) - you wouldn't miss to mention them ;-) Have you checked that the script actually gets to that foreach loop? E.g. by printing `echo 'processing ', count($arr), ' items'; foreach ($arr as ...`

Comment: no. the column type is ok.

Comment: I checked the foreach loop and it is going down after 1800 times. And i have no errors

Comment: @mrdeath4 check my post

Comment: max i can insert is 1779 rows! WHY?

Comment: die(mysql_error()) on a mysqli connection will probably return nothing. Should use mysqli_error()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above post about the **memory_limit** and **max_execution_time** should fix your problem. To catch any php issues you can add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '240');
```

I just want to suggest a more optimal way to do the import that will save you a query and might run faster

```
$sthi=mysqli_prepare($db_connect,"INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`, `minprice`, `s`, `js_id`, `pl`) VALUES (?, ?, ?,  ?, ?)") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
$sthi->bind_param("sssss", $w_name, $w_minprice,$w_s,$w_js_id,$pl);
$sthu=mysqli_prepare($db_connect,"UPDATE `mytable` SET `minprice` = ?, `s` = ? WHERE `js_id` = ? LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($db_connect));
$sthu->bind_param("sss", $w_minprice,$w_s,$w_js_id);
$i=0;
foreach ($arr as $temp) {
  $w_name = $temp[0];
  $w_minprice = $temp[2];
  $w_js_id = $temp[1];
  $w_s = $temp[3];

  @$sthi->execute();
  //If insert was unsuccessfull the record already exists
  if($sthi->affected_rows==1){
    $added++;
  }
  //Otherwise you need to update it - run the update startement
  else {
    if($sthu->execute()){
      if($sthu->affected_rows==1){
        $updated++;
      }
    }
    else echo $sthu->error."<br>";
  }
  flush();
  set_time_limit(30);

  //Not really necessary - just for debugging
  echo ++$i." u:".$updated." a:".$added."<br>";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. going to try this. But my code doesnt work even with  memory limit

Comment: yes the code is more or less fine, this will save you a database call on each record and will probably run a bit faster

Comment: i added this code to my php file. and got 500 eror in browser. Now i cant run this file even empty. What could it be?

Comment: there was a missing bracket after the update statement. please try again

Comment: now now errors. but script doesnt work . no action. just terminates

Comment: I just tested it with a simple array and now it should work. If a record was already updated/inserted it did nothing, so there are some additional checks  for affected rows there

Answer (score 2):

Possible memory or execution time limit issue.
Try adding below 2 lines on top of your php file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
```

Comment: no. just 1779 echos in my loop and after script doesnt work and no echos after

Comment: I can add something in my loop 1500 times. and all is working good. But no more 2 000

Comment: Your script is getting terminated. Did you add the 2 lines in my post and try running the script again?

Comment: do you run it in a browser or from cli? could be a page load timeout - you might need to flush the output to prevent the browser from timing out.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');

Comment: running from browser. and doesnt not work with these all params